# Excel macro paste just values

Tags: excel, vba

I written macro which copy date from one sheet to other.

```
Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Copy
Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Sheet2.Cells(erow, 1)
```

But in sheet 1 are formulas and I want to copy just values. How to change this code to solve my needs?

Comment: Investigate `PasteSpecial` and its arguments.

Comment: `Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Copy: Sheet2.Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Copy
Sheet2.Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Or:

```
Sheet2.Cells(erow, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value
```

Comment: Nice It is working. It is possible copy values with borders?