# Excel "if > copy > insert 1 line > paste > only values (from sheet to sheet)"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a macro to check if column "A3" is empty" then copy cells "A3:K3" from sheet "Outros" then insert a line in "Docs" sheet after line number 2 then paste only values to A3:K3 "Docs"...

The major problem is copy and paste only values + insert line, the nearest formula that I reach was

```
Worksheets("Outros").Range("A3:K3").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Docs").Range("A3:K3")
```

But with this I paste formulas not only values and it doesn't insert a line.

Comment: If the jist of your issue is how to paste values only, try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47925297/excel-macro-paste-just-values

Answer (score 0):

To shift a row down use:

```
Rows(3).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

Before you copy/paste

To paste the values and not formulas use:

```
.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you to make your own code:

```
Sub test()

Dim rng_one As Range
Dim rng_two As Range

Set rng_one = Worksheets("Outros").Range("A3:K3")
Set rng_two = Worksheets("Docs").Range("A3:K3")

' check if range is empty
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng_two) = 0 Then

' insert row above row 3
Worksheets("Docs").Rows("3:3").Insert Shift:=xlDown

' copy paste as values
rng_one.Copy
rng_two.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Excel.Application.CutCopyMode = False

End If

End Sub
```